# Is it possible to change the text color for a specific row in tblr?

Tags: color, tblr

I know how to change the background color of specific cells or rows / columns with `tblr` by using either `SetRow{color}` before the content or `row{rownumber} = {color}` in the definitions of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}
        {colspec={lcr}}
        \SetRow{cyan7} Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\
        Epsilon & Zeta & Eta & Theta \\
        Iota & Kappa & Lambda & Mu \\
        Nu & Xi & Omicron & Pi \\
        Rho & Sigma & Tau & Upsilon \\
        Phi & Chi & Psi & Omega \\
    \end{tblr}
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{tblr}{
            row{1} = {cyan7},
        }
        Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\
        Epsilon & Zeta & Eta & Theta \\
        Iota & Kappa & Lambda & Mu \\
        Nu & Xi & Omicron & Pi \\
        Rho & Sigma & Tau & Upsilon \\
        Phi & Chi & Psi & Omega \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Is it also possible to change the text color of a cell or row in a similar way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
row{1}         = {bg=cyan7},
row{3-4}       = {bg=red4},
cell{5-6}{3-4} = {bg=green4},
}
Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   & Delta   \\
Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     & Theta   \\
Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu      \\
Nu      & Xi    & Omicron & Pi      \\
Rho     & Sigma & Tau     & Upsilon \\
Phi     & Chi   & Psi     & Omega   \\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tblr}
{
row{1}         = {bg=cyan7,fg=gray4},
row{3-4}       = {bg=red4,fg=white},
cell{5-6}{3-4} = {bg=green4,fg=yellow8},
}
Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   & Delta   \\
Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     & Theta   \\
Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu      \\
Nu      & Xi    & Omicron & Pi      \\
Rho     & Sigma & Tau     & Upsilon \\
Phi     & Chi   & Psi     & Omega   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did not know there is a bg (background) and fg (foreground) differenciation.